# Nested $lookup in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have the following situation:

users: have the assign user roles

```
{
"baseData": {
    "organizations": [{
        "$oid": "60cc97caa27b7c6313c5a488"
    }],
    "accounts": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60cc87803a530000173f6d2e"
        },
        "kind": "anonymous",
        "deviceIdentifierID": "12D170E2-E19D-4DE9-9DD2-86CCC3A63A4F"
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "60cc87ac3a530000173f6d30"
        },
        "kind": "internal",
        "password": "$2b$12$TjBPxtL.LQbtE9kPk9UOlu5J7/MfpQg2k9YnJk15v4SRP7ZQUOTtS"
    }],
    "roles": [{
        "roleID": {
            "$oid": "60cb6c95abb7ab56d62be97d"
        },
        "resource": "60cc8716638ae25ee9bc4fcf",
        "validFrom": {
            "$date": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.138Z"
        },
        "validUntil": {
            "$date": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.138Z"
        }
    }, {
        "roleID": {
            "$oid": "60cb6c59abb7ab56d62be97b"
        },
        "resource": "60cc8716638ae25ee9bc4fcf",
        "validFrom": {
            "$date": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.219Z"
        },
        "validUntil": {
            "$date": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.219Z"
        }
    }, {
        "roleID": {
            "$oid": "60cb6c95abb7ab56d62be97d"
        },
        "resource": "60cc8a04d25826607c2ab2e4",
        "validFrom": {
            "$date": "2021-06-18T11:57:05.953Z"
        },
        "validUntil": {
            "$date": "2021-06-18T11:57:05.953Z"
        }
    }],
    "email": "Emanuel.syxgott@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "Emanuel",
    "lastName": "Bachmann",
    "username": "dulappen"
},
"system": {
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-18T11:46:08.525Z"
    },
    "modifiedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-18T13:31:33.282Z"
    }
},
"__v": 0
}
```

organizations: have a array an organization users

```
{
"baseData": {
    "users": [{
        "$oid": "60cc97a4a27b7c6313c5a484"
    }, "60cc87803a530000173f6d2d"],
    "name": "Goldhaus club",
    "email": "goldhaus.club@koram.at",
    "imageUrl": null,
    "description": null
},
"system": {
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-18T12:55:38.261Z"
    },
    "modifiedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-18T13:37:21.699Z"
    }
},
"__v": 0
}
```

userRoles: contain all available user roles (e.g. admin role)

```
{
"system": {
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-17T15:36:50.198Z"
    },
    "modifiedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-06-17T15:36:50.198Z"
    }
},
"permissions": [],
"title": "Organization Admin",
"alias": "ORGANIZATION_ADMIN",
"description": "All Permissions in the Organisation",
"__v": 0
```

}

i need a query that gives me the organisation data with the users and there roles

my aggregate query

```
const userPermissions = await Organization.aggregate([
  {
    $match: args.organizationQuery,
  },

  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'baseData.users',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'baseData.users',
    },
  },

  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'userroles',
      localField: 'baseData.users.baseData.roles.roleID',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'rolesFromUsers',
    },
  },

  {
    $addFields: {
      'baseData.users.rolesFromUserAlias': '$rolesFromUsers.alias',
    },
  },

  {
    $unset: [
      'baseData.users.baseData.organizations',
      'baseData.users.baseData.accounts',
      'baseData.users.system',
      'system',
    ],
  },

]);
```

result

```
[
    {
        "_id": "60cc97caa27b7c6313c5a488",
        "baseData": {
            "users": [
                {
                    "_id": "60cc87803a530000173f6d2d",
                    "baseData": {
                        "roles": [
                            {
                                "roleID": "60cb6c95abb7ab56d62be97d",
                                "resource": "60cc8716638ae25ee9bc4fcf",
                                "validFrom": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.138Z",
                                "validUntil": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.138Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "roleID": "60cb6c59abb7ab56d62be97b",
                                "resource": "60cc8716638ae25ee9bc4fcf",
                                "validFrom": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.219Z",
                                "validUntil": "2021-06-18T11:47:25.219Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "roleID": "60cb6c95abb7ab56d62be97d",
                                "resource": "60cc8a04d25826607c2ab2e4",
                                "validFrom": "2021-06-18T11:57:05.953Z",
                                "validUntil": "2021-06-18T11:57:05.953Z"
                            }
                        ],
                        "email": "alessandro@vondot.dat",
                        "firstName": "luk",
                        "lastName": "rhomberg",
                        "username": "rhomberg"
                    },
                    "__v": 0,
                    "rolesFromUserAlias": [
                        "ORGANIZATION_ADMIN",
                        "ORGANIZATION_PROMOTION",
                        "ORGANIZATION_EVENT"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "60cc97a4a27b7c6313c5a484",
                    "baseData": {
                        "email": "martin@koram.at",
                        "firstName": "Martin",
                        "lastName": "Rhomberg",
                        "username": "richmen69",
                        "roles": [
                            {
                                "roleID": "60cb6c12abb7ab56d62be97a",
                                "resource": "60cc97caa27b7c6313c5a488",
                                "validFrom": "2021-06-18T12:55:38.420Z",
                                "validUntil": "1970-01-01T00:00:02.022Z"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "__v": 0,
                    "rolesFromUserAlias": [
                        "ORGANIZATION_ADMIN",
                        "ORGANIZATION_PROMOTION",
                        "ORGANIZATION_EVENT"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "name": "Goldhaus club",
            "email": "goldhaus.club@koram.at",
            "imageUrl": null,
            "description": null
        },
        "__v": 0,
        "rolesFromUsers": [
            {
                "_id": "60cb6c12abb7ab56d62be97a",
                "system": {
                    "createdAt": "2021-06-17T15:36:50.198Z",
                    "modifiedAt": "2021-06-17T15:36:50.198Z"
                },
                "permissions": [],
                "title": "Organization Admin",
                "alias": "ORGANIZATION_ADMIN",
                "description": "All Permissions in the Organisation",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "60cb6c59abb7ab56d62be97b",
                "system": {
                    "createdAt": "2021-06-17T15:38:01.066Z",
                    "modifiedAt": "2021-06-17T15:38:01.066Z"
                },
                "permissions": [],
                "title": "Organization Promotion",
                "alias": "ORGANIZATION_PROMOTION",
                "description": "All Permissions for Promotions",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "60cb6c95abb7ab56d62be97d",
                "system": {
                    "createdAt": "2021-06-17T15:39:01.958Z",
                    "modifiedAt": "2021-06-17T15:39:01.958Z"
                },
                "permissions": [],
                "title": "Organization Event",
                "alias": "ORGANIZATION_EVENT",
                "description": "All Permissions for Events",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I only need to know what ROLE ALIAS the users have in the Organisations but i can not assign them correctly to the user.

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `let` and `pipeline` inside `$lookup` stage instead of `localField` and `foreignField` method. Have look at the documentation for reference.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately i can't come up with the solution either :/ Can you help me with an example ? @hhharsha36

Comment: I am not able to follow up with your sample data. Please give sample input and expected output with relations